# Naming form helper text f.input

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using

```
<%= f.input :firstName %>
```

where firstName is a field in the user model

However, the text beside the input box comes as firstName, is there a way to change the text beside the input box to first_name instead?

Comment: are you sing simple_form gem to construct forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using simple_form gem then try this out

```
  <%= f.input :firstName, label: 'first_name' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `<%= f.input :firstName, "first_name" %>